# storm hdfs bolt not working in HDP 2.2

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, kerberos, apache-storm

```
        I have tried executing storm hdfs sample program. I have created a jar file and copied the jar to the edge node of the cluster.

        Then I executed the below command

        java -cp storm-.1.jar:lib/*:lib/log4j.properties test.storm.sample.StormSampleTopology

        But, I am getting the below exception
        17434 [Thread-11-hdfs_bolt] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Exception encountered while connecting to the server : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name
        17448 [Thread-9-hdfs_bolt] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Exception encountered while connecting to the server : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name
        17457 [Thread-11-hdfs_bolt] ERROR backtype.storm.util - Async loop died!
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Error preparing HdfsBolt: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name; Host Details : local host is: "xxxx2002.xx.xxxxx.com/11.11.111.221"; destination host is: "x-xxxxx.xxxx.com":8020;
                at org.apache.storm.hdfs.bolt.AbstractHdfsBolt.prepare(AbstractHdfsBolt.java:96) ~[storm-hdfs-0.1.2.jar:na]
                at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3441$fn__3453.invoke(executor.clj:692) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
                at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__464.invoke(util.clj:461) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
                at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_45]
        Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name; Host Details : local host is: "xxx2002.xx.xxx.com/11.11.111.221"; destination host is: "x-xxxx.xxx.com":8020;
                at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:772) ~[hadoop-common-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:na]
                at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1472) ~[hadoop-common-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:na]
                at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399) ~[hadoop-common-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:na]
                at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232) ~[hadoop-common-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:na]
                at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.create(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
                at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.create(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:295) ~[hadoop-hdfs-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:na]
```

My key-tab file is located in the edge node itself. I have specified the location also in the property file
        Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please go through below link. I hope it may help you:https://support.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/204391288-hdfs-ls-command-fails-with-Server-has-invalid-Kerberos-principal